# Input Text File and Read First Character of Each Line + Count Occurences

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of the first character per line of a text file.

Example text file:

> A
>
> Ab
>
> Ac
>
> Ad
>
> B
>
> Ba

Example output:

> A : 4
>
> B : 2

Here's the code that I have so far, the issue is that it doesn't know which characters are the same so there multiple iterations of A, B, C, D, etc...

```
    string line;    
    char firstChar;        
    private void selectFile()
    {
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Open Text File";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text|*.txt";
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            readFile();
        }
    }

    private void readFile()
    {
        int counter = 0;

        StreamReader readTxt = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        while ((line = readTxt.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            charFreq();            
            counter++;
        }
    }

    private void charFreq()
    {
        firstChar = line.ToCharArray()[0];
        var charFreq =
            from c in firstChar.ToString().ToCharArray()
            group c by c into groupFrequencies
            select groupFrequencies;

        foreach (var c in charFreq)
            rTxtOutput.Text += (String.Format("{0} : {1}", c.Key, c.Count())) + "\r\n";
    }
```

What would be the proper way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ's `GroupBy`:

```
var query = File.ReadLines(filePath).Where(line => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                                    .GroupBy(line => line.First());
```

In case you want to account for empty lines:

```
var query = File.ReadLines(filePath).GroupBy(line => line.FirstOrDefault());
```

So the method should look like:

```
void PrintCharCount(string filePath)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
    {
         var query = File.ReadLines(filePath).Where(line => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                                             .GroupBy(line => line.First());

         foreach (var g in query)
             Console.WriteLine(g.Key + ": " + g.Count());
    }
}
```

And you don't need to use `StreamReader`,  `File.ReadLines` is designed for LINQ as it returns `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Note: `First` will thrown an exception for empty lines.

Comment: You might want to filter the blank lines with `Where` instead as `FirstOrDefault` will give the default `char` which is `\0`.

Comment: @w.b I replaced my code with your code. So it looks like: http://pastebin.com/d9PjCsLy 
I'm getting this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @AllTheGoodNamesWereTaken - your `readFile` method already returns the results so the other method is not needed, try to print with `foreach` directly after the query. The error appears because you didn't declare `line` variable in `charFreq`, but again you don't need that method.

Comment: @w.b Yes, that works. Is there anyway to make it so it sees lowercase as the same character as it's capital counterpart? Thanks

Comment: You can convert the chars inside `GroupBy` to one case with `Char.ToUpper` or `Char.ToLower`, like `....GroupBy(line => Char.ToUpper(line.First()));`